# How to Socket.io set CORS header

Tags: angular, angular7

Now,I am use `socket.io-client`for chat using angular 7

```
this.socket = io.connect('http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8084/action/event/kot');
```

but it can not connect with server and throw this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8084/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mqv9QP_' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

in backend i am use java spring mvc.. please tell me how can i solved it?

Comment: Enable CORS in your server.  check this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

Comment: You must configure your backend to send a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the localhost authorized.